# Use ndarray, prod and cumprod python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

How do I use ndarray, prod and cumprod to calculate the factorial of n?

```
def factorial (n):

n_array=np.array(n)
```

Is this the right start and how should I proceed?

Further, is it also possible to calculate factorials for 1 to n?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  First, why not simply use `numpy.math.factorial(n)`?  What do you mean by calculating factorials for 1 to n?  Do you mean like this: `numpy.array([numpy.math.factorial(x+1) for x in range(n)])`?

Comment: Better start with `np.arange(1, n+1)`. And then use `prod` and/or `cumprod`.

Comment: @mikebob `np.arange(1, n + 1).cumprod()` is list of first `n` factorials in likely a more performant way.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks, I figured that same thing out right before you said so :)